# nightwatch testing: .sendKeys and .keys not sending key clicks

Tags: testing, key, keypress, acceptance-testing, nightwatch.js

I am using node.js with nightwatch. It works great, my only issue is that my current application needs to be tested by 'pressing' all the arrow keys, and making sure the class name on the elements changes. I CANNOT get the sendKeys function to actually send a key press, and this test passes, when it should not :P. Any ideas?

```
module.exports = {
  'chosenTest.html' : function (browser) {
      browser
      .url(path)
      .waitForelementVisible('div[id=columns]', 1000)
      .assert.containsText('div[class="choosable chosen"], 'Test 1-0')
      .sendKeys('div[id=columns]', ShowText(browser), browser.Keys.DOWN_ARROW)
      .assert.containsText('div[class="choosable chosen"]', 'Test 1-0')
      .pause(1000)
      .end()
  }
}
```

Comment: Are you saying
      .sendKeys('div[id=columns]', ShowText(browser), browser.Keys.DOWN_ARROW) should fail?

Comment: Check what is showing up in selenium server logs

Comment: I know that Nightwatch.js has not sendKeys function, but keys function.

Comment: did you figure out how to do this? i have same issue

Answer (score 7):

The test you have shared should not pass. You should be seeing an error:

```
 ✖ ReferenceError: ShowText is not defined
```

Unless you have defined `ShowText` somewhere in your code ...?
What are you expecting `ShowText(browser)` to do?

Try:

```
.sendKeys('div[id=columns]', browser.Keys.DOWN_ARROW)
```

or, if you just want to send the keypress in the general window context:

```
.keys(browser.Keys.DOWN_ARROW)
```

> Working Example: [`.sendKeys('div[id=container]', browser.Keys.DOWN_ARROW)`](https://github.com/nelsonic/learn-nightwatch/blob/fa31120c08903808e38a39eb4f7cfa62e56a1622/test/e2e/tc.js#L13)

Note: `sendKeys` is an *alias* for `setValue`
see: [/lib/api/element-commands.js#L385](https://github.com/nightwatchjs/nightwatch/blob/8e342aa1cbb8e9124badae596349a5b71a8a17c3/lib/api/element-commands.js#L385) so it accepts the same params.

Answer (score 5):

You can try following way to press any key in nightwatch.js, i am pressing T and it is working superb!!

```
client.keys("t", function(done) {
    client.pause(5000);
    client.expect.element('#carousel_container').to.have.css('display').which.equals('block');
});
```

we are using above way because nightwatch.js Keys does not have any alphabet command in it's array, i have consoled and i haven't found any alphabet to press it.

```
Keys:
{ NULL: '',
  CANCEL: '',
  HELP: '',
  BACK_SPACE: '',
  TAB: '',
  CLEAR: '',
  RETURN: '',
  ENTER: '',
  SHIFT: '',
  CONTROL: '',
  ALT: '',
  PAUSE: '',
  ESCAPE: '',
  SPACE: '',
  PAGEUP: '',
  PAGEDOWN: '',
  END: '',
  HOME: '',
  LEFT_ARROW: '',
  UP_ARROW: '',
  RIGHT_ARROW: '',
  DOWN_ARROW: '',
  ARROW_LEFT: '',
  ARROW_UP: '',
  ARROW_RIGHT: '',
  ARROW_DOWN: '',
  INSERT: '',
  DELETE: '',
  SEMICOLON: '',
  EQUALS: '',
  NUMPAD0: '',
  NUMPAD1: '',
  NUMPAD2: '',
  NUMPAD3: '',
  NUMPAD4: '',
  NUMPAD5: '',
  NUMPAD6: '',
  NUMPAD7: '',
  NUMPAD8: '',
  NUMPAD9: '',
  MULTIPLY: '',
  ADD: '',
  SEPARATOR: '',
  SUBTRACT: '',
  DECIMAL: '',
  DIVIDE: '',
  F1: '',
  F2: '',
  F3: '',
  F4: '',
  F5: '',
  F6: '',
  F7: '',
  F8: '',
  F9: '',
  F10: '',
  F11: '',
  F12: '',
  COMMAND: '',
  META: '' 
},
```

You can press any key in above array easily like "client.keys(client.Keys.ENTER);".

Comment: client.api.Keys.ENTER ?

Comment: @galas0330, please accept it as answer if it is working perfectly fine for you.